# SCSF: display view from another view against button click

Tags: cab, scsf

i am facing one problem in SCSF.

I have two workspaces

1. MdiWorkspace
2. DeckWorkspace

i have two views in a module

1. Viewer (display in mdiworkspace)
2. Property Viewer (in deckworkspace)

in Viewer i have a button in toolbar whose purpose is to display PropertyViewer (another View).

how can i display this PropertyViewer in deckworkspace agaist button click event.

**NOTE:** i am not using Command[CommandName].AddInvoker(control, "click:) and CommandHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your toolbar sits in a SmartPart that implements the MVP pattern.  Have the button click event handler in the SmartPart fire an event that its presenter will handle.  Your presenter code would look like this:

```
// Presenter code

protected override void OnViewSet()
{
   this.View.ToolbarButtonClick += View_ToolbarButtonClick;
}

public void View_ToolbarButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove the handler so the property viewer 
    // will only be added the first time
    this.View.OnToolbarButtonClick -= View_ToolbarButtonClick;

    var propertyView = new PropertyViewer();
    this.WorkItem.Workspaces[WorkspaceNames.MyDeckWorkspace].Show(propertyView);
}
```